# Case feed QuickActionDefaultsHandler- Selecting a default email template not working

Tags: apex, email-template

Since Spring 15 it is possible to select a default email template by using a QuickActionDefaultsHandler. According to [the docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_interface_QuickAction_QuickActionDefaultsHandler.htm) you only need to:

> To specify default values for the standard Email Action on Case Feed,
>   create a class that implements QuickAction.QuickActionDefaultsHandler.

So I wrote this:

```
global class EmailComposer implements QuickAction.QuickActionDefaultsHandler {

    public static String DEFAULT_RESPONSE_TEMPLATE = 'Branded_Standard';

    global EmailComposer() { }

    // The only interface method
    global void onInitDefaults(QuickAction.QuickActionDefaults[] defaults) {

        QuickAction.SendEmailQuickActionDefaults sendEmailDefaults = getSendEmailFromCaseDefaults(defaults);

        if (sendEmailDefaults == null) return;

        EmailMessage emailMessage = (EmailMessage)sendEmailDefaults.getTargetSObject();   

        // set the template 
        List<EmailTemplate> templates = [select id from EmailTemplate where developername = : DEFAULT_RESPONSE_TEMPLATE limit 1];
        if (templates.size() == 0) return;

        sendEmailDefaults.setTemplateId(templates[0].Id);
        sendEmailDefaults.setInsertTemplateBody(false); 
        sendEmailDefaults.setIgnoreTemplateSubject(false);

    }

    private QuickAction.SendEmailQuickActionDefaults getSendEmailFromCaseDefaults(QuickAction.QuickActionDefaults[] defaults) {
        QuickAction.SendEmailQuickActionDefaults item;

        for (Integer j = 0; j < defaults.size(); j++) {

            if (!(defaults.get(j) instanceof QuickAction.SendEmailQuickActionDefaults)) continue;

            item = (QuickAction.SendEmailQuickActionDefaults)defaults.get(j);
            if (item.getTargetSObject().getSObjectType() == EmailMessage.sObjectType &&
               item.getActionName().equals('Case.Email') &&
               item.getActionType().equals('Email')) {
                return item;
            }
        }

        // couldn't find the defaults
        return null;
    }
}
```

Is there anywhere that I need to register this class? The specified template exists, but it is not automatically selected for new emails on a case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Documentation on this was indeed very bad, but I found a checkbox here:

**Customize > Cases > Support Settings > Enable Default Email Templates or The Default Handler for Email Action**

Comment: Good find Torsten! Sadly it is still not working, so I am keeping this open to see if some-one else can shed more light. Did you manage to implement a working Email handler?

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer for now since I am sure this is the missing part of the documentation. The app I'm working on does not use Case Feeds and I was expecting it to work on the Case details page when you press the `Send and Email` button.

Comment: Yes I did manage. Once you check the box you also have to select the Class implementing the Interface right below it. When turning on Debug Logs, do you see debug logs from inside the onInitDefaults method?

Comment: I did select the class too and the debug messages (I added some) didn't show in the Debug Logs, so this handler definitely doesn't get called from the Case details page `Send and Email`. It is a Feed only thing it seems. I ended up scrapping my handler and using [a URL button approach](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/14819/email-button-email-template)

Answer (score -1):

I Trid this on new emaail it working`global class EmailPublisherForCaseType implements QuickAction.QuickActionDefaultsHandler {

public static String DEFAULT_RESPONSE_TEMPLATE = 'test_email_template';
    // Empty constructor
    global EmailPublisherForCaseType() {
    }

```
// The main interface method
global void onInitDefaults(QuickAction.QuickActionDefaults[] defaults) {
QuickAction.SendEmailQuickActionDefaults sendEmailDefaults = (QuickAction.SendEmailQuickActionDefaults)defaults.get(0);
EmailMessage emailMessage = (EmailMessage)sendEmailDefaults.getTargetSObject(); 

Case c = [SELECT CaseNumber, Type FROM Case WHERE Id=:sendEmailDefaults.getContextId()];
List<EmailTemplate> templates = [select id from EmailTemplate where developername = : DEFAULT_RESPONSE_TEMPLATE limit 1];
    if (templates.size() == 0) return;    

// If case type is “Problem,” insert the “First Response” email template
```

// if (c.CaseNumber != null && c.Type.equals('Problem')) { 
        sendEmailDefaults.setTemplateId(templates[0].Id);   // Set the template Id corresponding to First Response
        sendEmailDefaults.setInsertTemplateBody(true);
        sendEmailDefaults.setIgnoreTemplateSubject(false);
    //}
}
}`

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour], and read [answer]. I don't really think that this answers the question being asked, so I've downvoted this answer. This answer, as is, constitutes what we call a "code dump" (code included with no explanation of what it does). This answer would be improved if you went into detail about _how_ it addresses the issue at hand.